# Angularfire2 SSR: firebase function build error

Tags: angularfire2

I'm trying to build an SSR for my application, I follow the documentation [Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/universal/cloud-functions.md) and everything is going great. Until now when I try to create a function for firebase hosting. I have a problem with the script `rm -r ./dist && cp -r ./dist . && tsc`. At **npm run build** throws error:

> rm: cannot remove './dist': No such file or directory
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! functions@ build: rm -r ./dist && cp -r ./dist . && tsc
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
>   logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-27T17_27_06_264Z-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! carsgram@0.0.0 build:functions: npm run --prefix functions build
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the carsgram@0.0.0 build:functions script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-27T17_27_06_371Z-debug.log

Any idea what causes it?

Comment: solved. it was enough to manually create the *src* folder in the function folder.

Comment: do you mean create "dist" directory?

Comment: OH yes "dist" folder.